# Assign values to objects in a specific namespace - R

Tags: r, namespaces, scope, gwidgets

I have a handler in gWidgets - R, where data is loaded in:

```
 handler=function(h,...){
                     fname <- gfile(text="Choose a file", 
                                    type="open", 
                                    action="print",
                                    handler = 
                                      function(h,...){
                                        do.call(h$action, list(h$file))
                                      }
                     )
                     load(fname)
                     .GlobalEnv$SETTINGS <- setwrite
                     svalue(status_bar) <- "Settings Loaded"
                   })
```

You can see that in order for the stuff loaded in to still be available after the function ends, at the end I put in in GlobalEnv, otherwise when the handler function ends the "setwrite" object created get's destroyed when the handler ends and the function is done. However this is not really my desired result, since the user has no need for the object, but other functions (not exported) in my package do need to make use of this object. I figured what I need to do is to put "setwrite" variable somewhere in those function's scope, like `package:pkgnamehere$SETTINGS <- setwrite` should go where the `.GlobalEnv$SETTINGS <- setwrite` line is, but it tells me the object package cannot be found. How can I do this correctly so as the objects made by a handler and put into scope of the packages non-expored functions/other gWidgets event handlers. (Non Exported because the idea is the user should just be able to use the GUI). Thanks.

Comment: A good way to do this is to use a reference class (which are super-charged environments in some sense). Then you can call methods on an instance to save values. As for your error, I think the environment (6 in your comment) would best be named.

Answer (score -1):

You can also store options in an environment your package.

```
pkgnamehere:::.options
```

See for example:

```
library(foreach)
foreach:::.foreachGlobals
<environment: 0x000000001448fae8>
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I would like to do - to have the GUI as the thing the user sees and interacts with, but all the variable, functions etc in the package namespace or environment so it's basically out of the way and can't really be messed with too much. Ho do I incorporate thins into my package i.e. so my package has .options or whatever environment - because my understanding is once a package is loaded with library() it can't be messed with anymore - since I tried putting  `assign("dnaseqs", dnaseqs, envir=6)` in my above handler but R won't have any of that `invalid 'envir' argument`.